# Getting a counter to move along Snakes and Ladders Board in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am currently trying to get counters to move along the board in my snakes and ladders game, I cant seem to get it working properly. This is my code, I cant seem to get the "counters" to come up within the printed grid to show the player their position. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public static void printBoard() {
    int numRows = 10;
    int numColumns = 10;
    int numSpaces = numRows * numColumns;
    int[][] board = new int[numRows][numColumns];

    for (int space = 0; space < numSpaces; space++)
    {
        int row = space / numRows;
        int column = space % numColumns;
        if (row % 2 == 0)
        {
            board[row][column] = (numSpaces - space);
        }
        else
        {
            board[row][(numColumns - column) - 1] = (numSpaces - space);
        }
    }

    for (int[] row : board)
    {
        for (int col : row)
        {
            System.out.printf("%4d", col);
        }
        System.out.println();

        for (int i=0; i<100;i++)
        {
            if(SnakesAndLadders.computerPos == i)
            {

                System.out.print("<"+SnakesAndLadders.computerPos+">");

            }//if
            else if(SnakesAndLadders.player1Pos == i)
            {

                System.out.print("(" + SnakesAndLadders.player1Pos + ")");

            }//else if

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple fix to the for loops that is printing the board

```
for (int[] row : board) {
    for (int col : row) {
        if(col==SnakesAndLadders.computerPos)
            System.out.printf("%4s", "<" + SnakesAndLadders.computerPos + ">");
        else if(col==SnakesAndLadders.player1Pos)
            System.out.printf("%4s", "(" + SnakesAndLadders.player1Pos + ")");
        else
            System.out.printf("%4d", col);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```